# Display Python >>> prompt in code chunk output

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

We are using rmarkdown to produce a book on Python programming. Code chunk options like `eval = TRUE` and `echo = TRUE` can be used to show the nicely formatted code in the output, run it, and show the result within the text.

What would be useful, though, would be to be able to sometimes prepend the code with the Python `>>>` prompt, to indicate code typed in an interactive terminal.

Is there a way to insert the `>>>` prompt as a prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**knitr** chunk option](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `prompt = TRUE` after you set `options(prompt = '>>> ')` in a previous code chunk, e.g.

````
```{r include=FALSE}
options(prompt = '>>> ')
```


```{python, prompt=TRUE}
print("hello world")
```
````

And adding `options(continue = '>>> ')` will add the `>>>` prompt prefix for multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks, great to get that tip straight from the horse's mouth. Unfortunately, though, it doesn't seem to work as well for Python like it does for R, as in this report: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1274

Comment: You may need to set `options(continue = '>>> ')` too (I don't know what characters a Python shell use for continuing a command).

Comment: Fantastic @Yihui , that `continue` option does indeed do the trick.